# Python Pandas velocity

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame, where the first column is when the customer entered the theater and second column is the name.

```
time name
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     B
5     B
6     C
7     B
8     C
```

I want to get average time for a customer entry (ignore the fact that customer has to leave in order to enter again).

I am trying to group by the data frame

```
df.groupby(['name']).agg({'time' : my_function()})
```

where

```
def my_function():
    for j in range(1,len(time)):
        total = total + time[j] - time[i] 
        i = i  + 1 
    return total / (len(time)-1)
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to be?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to take the average difference in times:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('name')

In [12]: g['time'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean())
Out[12]:
name
A    1.0
B    1.5
C    2.0
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Edit: I'm not sure whether you want this or simply the mean:

```
In [13]: g['time'].mean()
Out[13]:
name
A    2.000000
B    5.333333
C    7.000000
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks . It works. But what if  i need to pass 'time' as an argument to  a user defined function. The function takes in the parameter time and gives out the result.  Is it possible to implement diff() ?

Comment: @GauravP in apply/agg the function needs to take the subDataFrame/each group. tbh I'm a little confused at what you're trying to do :s